# how to retrieve multiple session values in thymeleaf when my session object contains more values?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My problem is i want to retrieve data from multiple tables using hibernate and i should that data on my view page.
I am successfully in bringing data from multiple tables using native sql .but the problem i am facing i am getting trouble to show the data in template engine using session attribute
(i got data from dao to controller in the of list .i kept the list object in session and i forwarded i return to template engine page .but in that page data is not coming only last row is coming )

### METHOD IN CONTROLLER:

```
@RequestMapping("/table")
public String table(Model model,HttpServletRequest request,Model modell)
{

    List<?> l=bookService.table();

    Iterator<?> l1=l.iterator();
    while(l1.hasNext())
    {
    Object  rows[] = (Object[])l1.next();
        System.out.println(rows[0]+"     "+rows[1]);
         one=Integer.parseInt(rows[0].toString());
         two=rows[1].toString();    
    }

    HttpSession hs=request.getSession();
    hs.setAttribute("lokesh",one);
    hs.setAttribute("lok",two);

    return "aim";
}
```

### MY CODE IN TEMPLATE PAGE IS:

```
    <tr>

      <td th:text="${session.lok}"></td>
      <td th:text="${session.lokesh}"></td>

    </tr>
```

I got this out put in jsp but in thymeleaf i am not getting

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `session` in your template but you don't have that reference in your controller.

As you have the same code working fine in jsp, you could access session attributes in Thymeleaf also using:

```
${#httpSession.getAttribute('foo')}
```

Check Thymeleaf documentation [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-objects).

So your code would be:

```
<td th:text="${#httpSession.getAttribute('lok')}"></td>
<td th:text="${#httpSession.getAttribute('lokesh')}"></td>
```

Comment: i'm getting only one value but session object contains multiple values.

Comment: Could you update your question with your actual results and which differences you have with your jsp code? Also, the answer is related to the code and your specific request, to work with Spring and Thymeleaf in the usual way, please check example: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#spring-thyme-seed-starter-manager